# How to removed permanent marker from skin?

Tags: cleaning

What if my friend or my foe made a big cross on my cheek with a permanent marker? How can I remove that big stubborn sign from my face?

Comment: Add a cross to your other cheek and tell everyone it's intentional.

Comment: As a hack you could [switch faces with your friend](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119094/).

Comment: @CaptainObvious I have seen some part of the movie. I don't want to go through such a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many options that will work. I'll name some:

- Soap in combination with water
- Anti-bug spray (use it on your hand or a towel and then rub your face)
- Suncream (or spray works also)
- Those small wet baby-cloths (clean your skin with hot water afterwards)
- Isopropyl Alcohol
- Nail polish or Acetone (on a towel and rub, clean it with hot water afterwards)
- Toothpaste (white and not in gel form, these don't work as good as others)
- Butter, put some butter on a piece of cloth and rub it on your skin.
- Water & Salt (not going to explain because it's the least comfortable and you don't want this, also takes up to 10 minutes)
- Coconut oil (Hot water + soap, rub it on your skin and then apply the oil)

**Most efficient**:

The most effective way would probably be using the hot water + soap first, and then apply the coconut oil. Rub it in and wash it off. If it isn't gone within 2 - 3 minutes then apply some Isopropyl Alcohol.

Comment: Pumice soap will take it right off (e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Gojo-0955-Natural-Orange-Cleaner/dp/B000CCOK6Q)

Comment: WD-40, apply with cotton ball moistened in it. Repeat until mark is removed.